# How to reverse the direction of grid Row in small screen for ant design

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I stuck while working with ant design. Please let me know how to reverse the direction of Row in small screen. The code is below here.

```
<Row justify="space-between" align='middle' style={{ height: "100%" }}>
  <Col>
   <div className={Login.language}>
    <div className="glob_icon">
      <Image src='/images/language_icon.png' height={20} width={20} />
    </div>
    <div className={Login.select_language}>
      <Space>
        <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
          <Button ghost type='link' style={{ color: "white" }}>
              <Space>
                 Português
                 <DownOutlined />
              </Space>
          </Button>
        </Dropdown>
      </Space>
    </div>
   </div>
  </Col>
  <Col>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: "15px", color: "white" }}>@ 2022 SpyIdol</Text>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: https://ant.design/components/grid/#components-grid-demo-flex-order
You need to pass order prop to each column.